# Async IO Error: SyntaxError: 'await' outside function

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await

Accoding to Async IO python docs -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html,
I tried exact same code in wsl ubuntu 20.04,

```
>>> import asyncio
>>> await asyncio.sleep(10, result='hello')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: 'await' outside function
>>>
```

According to there docs, this should be the code

```
$ python -m asyncio
asyncio REPL ...
Use "await" directly instead of "asyncio.run()".
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import asyncio
await asyncio.sleep(10, result='hello')
'hello'
```

Can someone tell me, What Am I doing wrong?

I expected the above response but did not work.

Comment: How did you open your shell?

Comment: Using `await` directly is only available in the asyncio REPL. See the code snippet at the top of the page you link to.

Comment: `python -m asyncio`

Comment: Open windows powershell and then wrote this - wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04
FYI - @AbdulNiyasPM